# Pyrogram - Sending videos

Tags: python, web-scraping, video, telegram, pyrogram

I'm trying to send videos via pyrogram, but every time I get the error

> pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.WebpageCurlFailed: Telegram says: [400 WEBPAGE_CURL_FAILED] - Telegram server could not fetch the provided URL (caused by "messages.SendMedia")

I tried with youtube videos links and with mp4 link, ex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I647GU3Jsc&pp=ygUHbmF0dXJhbA%3D%3D or https://server41.cherrycloud.net/DDL/ANIME/NarutoITA/Naruto_Ep_001_ITA.mp4

```
url = ""
@client.on_message(filters.text)
def send_video_from_url(c:Client, m:Message):
c.send_video(
    m.chat.id,
    url
)
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram only fetches videos that are below 10 MB. Anything that is above that threshold will raise an error in the API.

If you want to send videos larger than 10 MB, you'll have to download it to your server, and upload it to Telegrams Servers yourself. In the case of uploading videos over 10 MB, you'll have to supply the video resolution, duration and thumbnail yourself too.